# PHP/Mysql Order by and Rand()

Tags: php, mysql

How to write a mysql query with order by points Desc and rand().

Query

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC
```

I want to sort data based on highest points and random too. I am making a leaderboard. If 2 persons have the same point just for sake of difference  I want to shuffle the order. Whats the another solution.

Comment: I just read rand() some times slower the query based on the result, can we use shuffle()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give each result a random number and order the result first by points DESC then by the random value:

```
SELECT *, RAND() random FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, random ASC
```

Probably there's also the solution with:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, RAND()
```

But I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, RAND() is working also, first one is creating doubts in my mind, complexity wise. Thanks

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER dear 
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, RAND()
this will not work.
because only we can sort the data on one order. you can only use RAND() or based on desc not both

Comment: This query is working SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, RAND()

Answer (score 0):

dear SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, RAND() this will not work. because only we can sort the data on one order. you can only use RAND() or based on desc not both

Query provided by @timeSpinter is right, you can use one criteria to ordered data.

like

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND()
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY DESC
```

Comment: "we can sort the data on one order". Well technically we can sort data by many orders but only one **direction**.

Comment: @Irfan, This query is working SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, RAND()

Comment: @roger see the result, is the result set is vary on every refresh??