# changing column encoding mysql to appear as arabic language

Tags: php, mysql

i have table in data base and there is a column have strange language like below '20795, '1818300', '33018964', '1022251015', 'Completed without ID number',

'ÔÇÑÚ ÇáãÑÛäì - ÇáÚãÇÑå ÈåÇ ãÍá ÓÇãÓæäÌ - ÈÌæÇÑ ÚãÇÑå ÇÈæÛÇáì - ÇáÏæÑ ÇáÓÇÈÚ-ÇáãÇÙå-ÇáÞÇåÑå'

but it was inserted as an arabic language using PHPRunner program .
my question is how to update that column to seen as arabic language in mysql .
i need to fix the old data .

note : values appeared normally on arabic language on the webpage 
my problem how to change it in DB ,.

note : the format of this table , column is UTF8

Answer (score 0):

You may easily set utf8 to your tables if you are using SQLYog.

Just right click on db, table, column name and click on alter option and set to

Database Chartset = utf8 Database Collation = utf8_general_ci .

Just Enjoy ....

Comment: for reference more you can visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337965/php-mysql-order-by-and-rand

Comment: Irfan, No link was posted

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html This should help you though Hercal

Comment: i am using mysql Administrator , also the encoding in utf8 and same problem exist

Comment: @Bowersbros sorry dear, mistakenly enter key pressed

Comment: @Hercal2020, have you tried the collation? It should be something like ci_general_utf8

Comment: @bowersbros , yes the Collation  is utf8_general_ci . and the Chartset is UTF8 , what should i do ???

Comment: Does the data show correctly when using MySQL via command line?

Comment: @bowersbros ,...no  it shows as strange language.,,but it shows right on the web

Comment: Are you able to screenshot it for us please?